# Java Beginner: Subclasses and Superclasses -Can you remove values?

Tags: java, attributes, behavior, superclass

I'm a Java beginner and I'm looking into subclasses and superclass's.

I know you can add values/attributes/behaviour that aren't in a superclass to a subclass to make it more 'task specific'.

But my question is, can I remove an attribute or behaviour value that belongs in a superclass from a subclass?

Comment: What do you mean by remove attribute? Can you explain a usecase for this? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend` implies inheritance. You don't have a precise choice over what you can inherit and what you can't.

If parent class has decided to expose some public variables etc, sub class cannot alter that.

If the parent class doesn't want to expose some fields those can be marked as `private`.

Also: A class should be open for extending it but closed for changing it.

Comment: that is not the right way to do it in my opinion... `private` just marks the visibility. visibility != existence

Comment: @PhilippSander  Sure, sub class won't be able to delete a field from super class. `private` is the advised solution, the field's existence would never be exposed outside. The decision must be of parent class's creator and not of any one who uses it.

Answer (score 7):

simple answer:

No you can't AND you shouldn't!

It should always makes sense that a superclass has an attribute.

Take a look at this: [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_Substitution_Principle)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the access level modifiers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove superclass's variables and methods from subclass, but you can hide fields and override methods in subclass:

```
class Employee {
    String name = "Employee";
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Do some work");
    }
}

class Programmer extends Employee {
    String name = "Programmer";
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Write programs");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not overriding.  It is hiding.  The field declared in the superclass exists in instances of the subclass too.

Comment: Stephen, maybe I wrong with terminology. You mean, that 'name' field of Employee is hidden in Programmer (we can get it in Programmer by super.name anyway), but method work() is overriden, right?

Comment: That is correct.  But the different terms have different meanings.  A hidden method can be seen, but an overridden method cannot be called from the outside.